# Unity - How to make trail renderer lasts after game object destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a gun on unity, but I'm having a problem with trail renderer. I made this `code` to destroy the bullet when it collides, but when it is destroyed the trail stops in the air and after that `time trail renderer` it disappears, i want the trail to continue and slowly disappear.

[bullet trail stopped in the air, and then disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgn7x.png)

I tried to do something but didn't work, this is my code.

```
    public TrailRenderer Trail;

    private void Awake() {
        Trail = GetComponentInChildren<TrailRenderer>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll) {
        Debug.Log("aaa");
        Destroy(gameObject);

        Trail.transform.parent = null;
        Trail.autodestruct = true;
        Trail = null;
    }
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change order? You destroy the object before you change the parenting ;)

Try

```
Trail.transform.parent = null;
Trail.autodestruct = true;

Destroy(gameObject);
```